# Determine second word in a user typed sentence

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a second word typed in a sentence. I have the first word determined and I'm having trouble finding how to get JUST the second word. This is what I've tried:

```
    String strSentence = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter a sentence with at" + " least 4 words",
            "Split Sentence", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    int indexOfSpace = strSentence.indexOf(' ');

    String strFirstWord = strSentence.substring(0, indexOfSpace);
/*--->*/String strSecondWord = strSentence.substring(indexOfSpace, indexOfSpace);
    Boolean blnFirstWord = strFirstWord.toLowerCase().equals("hello");
    Boolean blnSecondWord = strSecondWord.toLowerCase().equals("boy");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The sentence entered: " + strSentence 
            + "\nThe 1st word is " + strFirstWord
            + "\nThe 2nd word is " + strSecondWord
            + "\nIs 1st word: hello? " + blnFirstWord
            + "\nIs 2nd word: boy? " + blnSecondWord);
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use `String.split()` in your homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the second word from the first space to the first space (its going to be empty).  I suggest you take it until the second space or the end.

```
 int indexOfSpace2 = = strSentence.indexOf(' ', indexOfSpace+1);
 String strSecondWord = strSentence.substring(indexOfSpace+1, indexOfSpace2);
```

If you can use split you can do

```
 String[] words = strSentence.split(" ");
 String word1 = words[0];
 String word2 = words[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int indexOfSpace = strSentence.indexOf(' ');
String strFirstWord = strSentence.substring(0, indexOfSpace);
strSentence = strSentence.substring(indexOfSpace+1);
indexOfSpace = strSentence.indexOf(' ');
String strSecondWord = strSentence.substring(0, indexOfSpace);
strSentence = strSentence.substring(indexOfSpace+1);
indexOfSpace = strSentence.indexOf(' ');
String strThirdWord = strSentence.substring(0, indexOfSpace);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first word is defined as the text between the start of the sentence and the first space, right?  So `String strFirstWord = strSentence.substring(0, indexOfSpace);` gets that for you.

Similarly, the second word is defined as the text between the first space and the second space.  `String strSecondWord = strSentence.substring(indexOfSpace, indexOfSpace);` finds the text between the first space and the first space (which is an empty String), which isn't what you want; you want the text between the first space and the *second* space...

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex:

```
String second = input.replaceAll("^\\w* *(\\w*)?.*", "$1");
```

This works by matching the entire input while capturing the second word and replacing what's matched (ie everything) with what was captured in group 1.

Importantly, the regex is crafted such that everything is optional, which means that if there's no second word, a blank results. This will also work with the edge case of blank input.

Another plus is it's just one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` method of `String` class. It part the string using a pattern. For example:

```
String strSentence = "word1 word2 word3";
String[] parts = strSentence.split(" ");

System.out.println("1st: " + parts[0]);
System.out.println("2nd: " + parts[1]);
System.out.println("3rd: " + parts[2]);
```